# sqlite3 fetching data based on epoch time

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, epoch, splunk

I am new to sqlite3 and I created an sqlite3 database named result that has _time table that lists IP addresses based on epoch time I queried from Splunk. I am trying to fetch data based on _time (epoch time) table from my sqlite3 database.

Here is a copy of _time and IP addresses listed in sqlite3 database:

```
1535139799|2002:8672:5ebf::8672:5ebf
1535139799|2002:8672:5ebf::8672:5ebf
1535131073|2002:8672:ba8a::8672:ba8a
1535131058|2002:8672:ba8a::8672:ba8a
1535131058|2002:8672:ba8a::8672:ba8a
1535131413|2002:8672:5ebf::8672:5ebf
1535131413|2002:8672:5ebf::8672:5ebf
1535120613|2002:8672:5ebf::8672:5ebf
1531944594|41.212.170.179
1531944594|38.108.250.243
```

The problem is, no matter the commands I've tried, it always outputs ALL of the IP address. I just need the IP addresses from x number of days (30 days ago). I've looked [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771580/deleting-android-sqlite-rows-older-than-x-days) and followed many examples but still no success. I've also looked at [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE _time < (DATE('now', '-5 day'));
SELECT * FROM result WHERE _time > (DATE('now', '-5 days')); 
SELECT * FROM result WHERE _time > (SELECT DATE('now', '-7 day'))
```

I've changed the number of 'days', but the commands still fetch all of the listed IP address. I just need to fetch IP addresses from x days ago (10 days ago or 30 days ago). I am assuming that sqlite3 cannot read epoch time in my tables?

I am stuck in this problem for days now. I will continue to look for a solution, I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: I think your `_time` is Unixepoch (seconds since 1970-01-01), so try `_time > strftime('%s',DATE('now', '-5 day'))`.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher You don't need the date() part - just `strftime('%s', 'now', '-5 day')`

Comment: @Shawn good to know. i'm not familiar with sqlite, just combined OPs tries with the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to convert one of the sides of the comparison argument to be of the same type as the other argument.

You can convert either the adjusted **now** (right hand argument) to seconds using :-

```
srtftime('%s','now',your_adjustment) or you could adjust the
```

Or you could convert the **_time** column to date (yyyy-mm-dd) format using

```
date(_time,'unixepoch')
```

Using your first example then this could be either :-

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE _time < strftime('%s','now', '-5 day');
```

or it could be :-

```
SELECT * FROM result WHERE date(_time,'unixepoch') < date('now', '-5 day');
```