# Delete record after 30 minutes SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to remove records that are 30 minutes from the current time.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO available (server, timestamp) VALUES (?, datetime('now'))", (server))
```

It's inserting the correct timestamp with no issues. However, how would I go about removing records 30 minutes from the timestamp?

I'm using a while loop with 10 seconds intervals.

Comment: Did you try comparing the timestamp of each record with the current time, and if the difference is more than 30 minutes deleting the record?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve, but as I'm pretty new to Python, I'm not sure how to go about it

Comment: This should have answered your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771580/deleting-android-sqlite-rows-older-than-x-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM available WHERE timestamp <= datetime('now','-30 minutes')"; 
c.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: @Jonathon and @benjessop you must change `date(....)` to `datetime(....)`.